# Why does a variable (random number) act like a 'generator'

Tags: python, arrays, indexing, typeerror, generator

I am trying to make a simple rock paper scissors game on python

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'generator' and 'str'
```

This was the error message, that was given after I placed a randomizer in the code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-4-dea4c40cfdcd> in <module>()
 49   if key == 'q':
 50     break
---> 51   player_score, comp_score = gameplay(player_score, comp_score)
 52   print('Score is: YOU ', player_score, ' - ', comp_score, ' COMPUTER')
 53   print('')

 <ipython-input-4-dea4c40cfdcd> in gameplay(player_score, comp_score)
 12 
 13   comp_move = moves[randomize]
 ---> 14   battle = key + '-' + comp_move
 15 
 16   comp_print = (word for position, word in ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'] if position == randomize - 1)
```

What is this 'generator' object?? In google they say it is made from using a loop, so it is a kind of sequence, but didn't generate it with loop, rather than while loop. Is this loop the reason for the error? Moreover, I am not using the sequence of letters, but only a single letter from it, and I am calling it with its position number in the sequence?

Here is the code until the error:

```
 from random import randint

 player_score = 0
 comp_score = 0
 key = None

 # Setting the rules
 choices = {'r-s': 'rock breaks scissors', 'p-r': 'paper envelopes rock', 's-p': 'scissors cut paper'}
 moves = {1: 'r', 2: 'p', 3: 's'}

 def gameplay(player_score, comp_score):

   comp_move = moves[randomize]
   battle = key + '-' + comp_move
```

---

Here are more details about the code:
the random number is initialized inside the while loop

```
while True:
  randomize = randint(1, 3)
  print('<r>ock, <p>aper or <s>cissors? Press any key to continue; <q> for exit')
  key = check_input()
  if key == 'q':
    break
  player_score, comp_score = gameplay(player_score, comp_score)
  print('Score is: YOU ', player_score, ' - ', comp_score, ' COMPUTER')
  print('')
  key = None
```

however, I am using a single variable not a sequence of variables here, or am I wrong?

---

As far as I have looked up for answers and explanations of the  arrays in Python, I have found two different approaches to solve this, so far:

The first was by the means of the example from @John Coleman using 'for loop' and simplifying the expression with index of array:

```
items = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']

  for word in items:
    if items.index(word) == randomize - 1:
      print('Computer played: ', word)
```

The other approach was to improve the expression

```
item = (word for position, word in ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'] if position == randomize - 1)
```

with the function 'enumerate':

```
  item = [word for position, word in enumerate(['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']) if position == randomize - 1]
  print('Computer played: ', item[0])
```

Actually, the problem appeared in the first place due to the lack of indexes of the arrays in Python, thus you have to find out how to make them by yourself.

Both of the given solutions work, so the topic could be considered 'closed'.

Comment: `comp_print` has type `generator`, as you use a generator expression to define it. It's not clear how `comp_move` (really, `moves[randomize]`) becomes a `generator`.

Comment: could you post your whole code?

Comment: You need to show us the value of `key` that is in effect at the time of the error - the only assignment in the code you posted is `None`, which would produce an entirely different error, so it must have been reassigned somewhere else.

Comment: Generator is a fundamental (and useful) concept of python - it's essentially an object that generates values when you iterate over it. Some of the comprehension expressions and built-in functions in python produce generators. You can cast a finite generator into a list or tuple to see what's in it list(generator). Or you can next(iter(generator)) to just see the next element.

Comment: @chepner, how could the random number be a generator?, where does this come from? Because, every time I have used random number, it gives int or float numbers. Yes, I am using dictionaries here (as sequences of chars), but in the given equation I used only a single char from the dictionary!!

Comment: You never defined `randomize` in the code that you posted. Please provide a [mcve]. You haven't provided enough information for anyone to see what the problem is.

Comment: @John Coleman: randomize = randint(1, 3)

Comment: Relevant code should be in the question not the comments. Adding `randomize = randint(1, 3) ` is still not enough to make the error reproducible by others. For one thing, @jasonharper is undoubtedly correct that you reassigned `key` somewhere but neglected to show how. A [mcve] should have the property that someone can copy/paste it into a Python IDE and run as is to replicate the error.

Comment: Apparently the function `check_input()` (which you don't show) returns a generator. This is still far from being reproducible by anyone reading the question.

Comment: The randomizer was not the problem, It really returns int, but here is the check_input() function, that assigns the variable 'key':   ``` def check_input():
  inputed = None
  while True:
    try:
      inputed = input('Press a key: <r>, <p>, <s>, or <q>')
      inputed = (letter for position, letter in ['p', 'q', 'r', 's'] if letter == inputed)
      break
    except IndexError:
      print('Wrong input! Press a key: <r>, <p>, <s>, or <q>')

  return inputed ```

Comment: Please edit the question to include the relevant code `inputed = (letter for position, letter in ['p', 'q', 'r', 's'] if letter == inputed)` causes `inputed` to be a generator expression (one that doesn't really make sense), which you then return. That how `key` becomes a generator.

Comment: @John Coleman, you were right, this expression gives the generator object, but now how can I transform it into a single char from the array??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `check_input` is overly complicated and inadvertently returns a generator object (one which would furthermore throw an error if you attempted to use it).

Instead, just do something like:

```
def check_input():
  while True:
    inputed = input('Press a key: <r>, <p>, <s>, or <q>')
    if inputed  in ['p', 'q', 'r', 's']:
        return inputed
    print('Wrong input! Press a key: <r>, <p>, <s>, or <q>')
```

Comment: Yes, this gives a very simple and working explanation of the question. However, there is the same type of error in this part of the code:   comp_print = (word for position, word in ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'] if position == randomize - 1)
  print('Computer played: ', comp_print). This is what it returns in the console: <r>ock, <p>aper or <s>cissors? Press any key to continue; <q> for exit
Press a key: <r>, <p>, <s>, or <q>r
Computer played:  <generator object gameplay.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x7ff78a33a8d0>
comp wins
Score is: YOU  0  -  1  COMPUTER

Comment: I tried to make the same with the second part, but here is what happens:  ```  for position, word in ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']:
    if position == randomize - 1:
      print('Computer played: ', word)``` `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

Comment: What to do now??!